# Suppose $X$~$N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Then $\epsilon$ ~$N(0, \sigma^{2})$ where $\epsilon$ is the residuals of the model?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, regression

Suppose that $X$ is a sample of $n$ observations where $n$ is very large. We want to predict $Y$ and fit a regression model using ($X$,$Y$).

Is the following statement a proposition? If not, why? This is not homework, rather a question out of curiosity...

**Suppose $X$~$N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Then $\epsilon$ ~$N(0, \sigma^{2})$ where $\epsilon$ is the residuals of the model $Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X + \epsilon$.**

Comment: "$\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$" is a common assumption when *defining* the linear model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$. It's uncommon for the covariate $X$ to also follow the same distribution.

Comment: There are a lot of things abnormal about what you wrote.  It would be more usual to write the model as $y_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_i + \epsilon_i$ where the $\epsilon_i$ are errors in the model.  It is common to assume that the errors have zero expectation and quite common to assume they are independent of each other and normally distributed with equal variances.  There is no need to make the same assumptions about the $X_i$ (they do not even have to be random) and it is unlikely that the $X_i$ have the same variance as the $\epsilon_i$...

Comment: .. When you fit and estimate the parameters in the model and get  $\hat y_i=\hat \beta_{0} + \hat\beta_{1} x_i$, the residuals are $y_i-\hat y_i$, and these do not have the same distribution as the original errors

Comment: Thank you angryavaian and Henry!  Why must we generally assume the errors be normally distributed with common variance when creating a regression model?